# Need span title in Xpath

Tags: xpath

I need span title text (RS_GPO) as my xpath output
Here is code:

```
<TD id="celleditableGrid07"  nowrap="nowrap"    style='padding:0px;'  >`
<DIV class='stacked-row'>
<span id="form(202567).form(TITLE).text" >
<span  title='RPS_AEM3'>RPS_AEM3</span>
</span>
</DIV>

<DIV class='stacked-row-bottom'>
<span id="form(202567).form(CONTENT).text" >
<span  title='RS_GPO'>RS_GPO</span>
</span>
</DIV>
```

My intention for xpath is I want catch text “RS_GPO” in to a variable.
Because this is system generated text.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
//span[@title='RS_GPO']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='stacked-row-bottom']/span[@id='form(202567).form(CONTENT).text']/span[@title='RS_GPO']
```

Comment: Thanks shubham for Answering.
But i am looking for "RS_GPO" text as output of my xpath.
because this is dynamic text. so we can not use this in out xpath.

Comment: You can use dynamic xpath in that case .. just you need to replace RS_GPO with varaiable using + operator i.e string concatenation ... but in tht case you should know the title as prerequisite

Comment: is these two line of code is also dynamic..

<DIV class='stacked-row-bottom'>
<span id="form(202567).form(CONTENT).text" >

Comment: yes but here at least I am getting this form No."form(202567)" from some other variable, rest are static.

Comment: You can do something like this if you know what you are looking for .. for example if you know that you need to search RS_GPO then use something like below:-            String vari = "RS_GPO";
            String xpathmade = "//span[@title='"+vari+"']";

Comment: Shubham,
My intation for xpath is I want catch text “RS_GPO” in to a variable.
 Because this is system generated text. 
That’s why I want xpath using below code only.
 <DIV class='stacked-row-bottom'> <span id="form(202567).form(CONTENT).text

Answer (score 0):

```
//span[contains(@id,'form(CONTENT).text')]/span
```

If you want the content of the title attribute instead of the element's text content, then:

```
//span[contains(@id,'form(CONTENT).text')]/span/@title
```